# Passing two values with in the context dictionary in OpenERP

Tags: python, dictionary, odoo

I have been trying to return values through the context dictionary. The scenario is that I have a form button which will return another form . Here I am passing the values of this form to be set on the fields of the other form.

I have passed one value successfully through context but when I try to pass 2 values , I still get only 1 value on the other form. My both fields are many2one. My python code is shown below:

```
  def creates(self,cr,uid,ids,context):
        for id in ids:
            deg_obj=self.pool.get('deg.form').browse(cr,uid,id)
            my_id=int(deg_obj.my_products)
        prr= int(deg_obj.categg_temp)
        pch= int(deg_obj.categ_temps)
        cch= int(deg_obj.categ_temp2)
        return{
              'view_type': 'form',
              'view_mode': 'form',
              'res_model': 'product.product',
              'context':{'default_pr':prr,'default_ch':pch}, 
              'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
              'nodestroy':False,
              'target': 'inline',
              }
```

May be there is some syntax problem, but I am not getting any error. Please guide me on this or share some alternative to achieve this.

Comment: `id` is the name of a built-in function in Python - you could try changing the name of the variable in the `for` loop.

Comment: `prr= int(deg_obj.categg_temp)` .. `categg`?

Comment: categg_temp is the field value of this form.

Comment: @ajcr id is used to get the current object of the form

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to override the default_get() method of the product.product to get value passed through the context and put them on the fields.